# How to set environment variables in a PowerShell script defined in a configuration file?

Tags: powershell, for-loop, batch-file, call

I have a simple preferences system in batch.
The bat renames the .ini to a .bat and call it.
The variables or options that in the .ini will be initialized in that way.
So I can use it to create a multilingual batch file.
Now I started learning PowerShell. I want to have the same function.

My files:

MyFile.bat - initialize the ini and make some other stuff...:

```
ren User-Generated\preferences.ini preferences.bat
call User-Generated\preferences.bat
ren User-Generated\preferences.bat preferences.ini
echo Your language is %locale%.
...
```

And here we have the preferences.ini - in her, there saved all options eg. language:

```
set locale=de
set cancelled=true
set firstrun=false
```

Now I can create the same preferences.ini for PowerShell:

```
$locale="de"
$cancelled="true"
$firstrun="false"
```

My question:

I need to call the ini with a PowerShell script.
How to do that?

@mofi wrote, that we could it make with this for loop either:

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%~dp0User-Generated\preferences.ini") do set "%%I"
```

But how to "convert" it to PowerShell?

Thanks for your help!

JJB

Answer (score 0):

You define some environment variables by using [set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/set_1).
You could do the same in PowerShell by using the [$env](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7.1).

```
$env:locale="de"
$env:cancelled="true"
$env:firstrun="false"
```

To call your bat script, you could use the [call operator](https://ss64.com/ps/call.html).

```
& 'cmd.exe' @('/c', 'call', 'LoadPreferences.bat')
```